# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) in python selenium webdri

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
import os
from Ultimatix_login import ultimatix_login1
from searchtest import searchtest

directory1=os.getcwd()
class main_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Issue(self):
        test1=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ultimatix_login1)
        tests2=unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(searchtest)
#combining both the test cases into one suite
        suite=unittest.TestSuite([test1,tests2])
        outfile=open(directory1,"\maintest.html","w")
        runner1=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
            output=outfile,
            report_title="test_report",
            descriptions="Main_test"
            )
        runner1.run(suite)

#opening the report file
#outfile=open(dir +"\testreport.html","w")

if  __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am trying to generate html Test report but the test cases are executing properly but html report is not generating pls help me out this..
Thank you.

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? The error itself means that you are giving a string as input of a function that instead requires an integer. Note that you are probably giving something like " 1" instead 1. In that case you can cast to int with int(strin_to_be_casted)

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

```
outfile=open(directory1,"\maintest.html","w")
```

According to the [documentation of the built-in `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), its first three arguments are expected to be

1. the *file path* (a string)
2. the *mode* in which the file is opened (a string)
3. the *buffering policy* (an integer)

The way you are invoking the function, you are passing the following arguments:

1. *file path* → `directory1`
2. *mode* → `"\maintest.html"`
3. *buffering* → `"w"` – This is wrong, an integer is expected.

It seems that you actually want to use `<directory1>\maintest.html` as the file path and `"w"` as the opening mode.

In order to do that, use the [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function:

```
outfile = open(os.path.join(directory1, "maintest.html"), "w")
```

(Note that you have to omit the `\`, which would have meant [something different](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) anyway.)

Comment: Thank you mkrieger1 it is working now but still showing error like **TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'TextIOWrapper'**.would you please check it for once.

Comment: **EC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\case.py:629: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper** this error is comming please help me out this.

Comment: I don't know right now what is causing that error. You will have to do some debugging yourself. Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/